# Alternative to POA CORBA in web services world

Tags: web-services, distributed-computing, policy, corba

I have been told that CORBA programming is not modern and that I should
use newer technologies. OK ...

But what I appreciated in the CORBA world was the POA (despite its complexity)
because it was very flexible and gave me the opportunity to choose 
adequate policies to my distributed objects.

Are there things similar to POA in the WEB Services world ? or should I code
it myself ?

Thanks for your replies !

Comment: The two aren't really comparable. CORBA is about distributed objects, Web Services are about, well, services.

Comment: OK ... but if CORBA is dead, what is the standard to be used for building distributed objects ? (I am aware of ICE but it is a product, not a standard).

Comment: If you want distributed objects, then (in my humble opinion) CORBA is still a good choice.

Comment: What exactly about the POA makes it compelling to you? That would help us figure out the best answer to give you. Also, if you're happy with CORBA and the POA then go ahead and use it. Just because it isn't modern or featured daily on highscalability.com doesn't mean it can't meet your needs.

Answer (score 1):

[Batches](http://www.cs.utexas.edu/~wcook/projects/batches/index.htm) are a new approach to relational database access, remote procedure calls, and web services.

A Remote Batch statement combines remote and local execution: all the remote code is executed in a single round-trip to the server, where all data sent to the server and results from the batch are communicated in bulk. RBI supports remote blocks, iteration and conditionals, and local handling of remote exceptions. RBI is efficient even for fine-grained interfaces, eliminating the need for hand-optimized server interfaces.

Batch services also provide a simple and powerful interface to relational databases, with support for arbitrary nested queries and bulk updates. One important property of the system is that a single batch statement always generates a constant number of SQL queries, no matter how many nested loops are used.